# Salesforce Mobile SDKv10.2.0 Issue Login

Tags: mobile, login, authorization, react-native

While changing the oauthRedirectURI to a custom url ex: https://myURL.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success (production) I can login successfully but it got stuck to the Remote Access Application Authorization white page, I can Log into the same client Id on a different framework and different SDK version (Ionic 3 and SDK 8).
I am currently building in react-native 0.71.15 and SDK Mobile 10.2.0 and react-native-force 10.2.0 ("git+https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-ReactNative.git#v10.2.0")

Have also tried React Native 0.70.13, 0.70.1, and SDK 11. Once i build with test.salesforce.com default url, everything works fine.

[image]

Please note that i am only getting this behavior in production environment and it's the only environment i have SSO login as mandatory.
Have you ever experienced this?

Thanks in advance